# Should I trash old CS6 programs before reinstalling CS6 on same disc?

Tags: macos

After experiencing hardware problems on a MacMini, I need to reinstall CS6 on the internal SSD. I used Utilities/Adobe/CS6 installer to uninstall CS6 programs. These remain on the SSD but are now inoperable. Is it advisable to manually remove and trash these old CS6 program files on SSD (freeing up disc space) before reinstalling from original CS6 DVD?

Answer (score 2):

Er... in answer to my own question, I came upon the Creative cloud cleaner tool at https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html, followed instructions and cleared all old adobe CS applications before reinstalling CS6.